Google calender event response, to a non gmail email
I am using google calendar, but not using Gmail. I have added an alternative email address in the google calendar settings. When I create an event and invite guests, their response is only sent to my Gmail. Is it possible to make the responses go to my non-Gmail email, other than making Gmail redirect the response emails? Is there a setting in google calendar that lets me do that?

From which account are you creating the event from?

To me it seems like the event is always considered to be created from my Gmail login. I have linked my alternative (non-gmail) email to the Google account. But even when I sign into Google with the non-gmail, it still show me as being logged into the account, with my Gmail.

If you have linked your Gmail to a non-gmail account, your non-gmail account is automatically just being used as an alias to your Gmail account. When you log in to Google Account (Google workspace e.g. Gmail, Calendar, Docs) using non-gmail account it will automatically login the gmail account linked to it since the other domain is a third party email which can not access the Google tools since they are being managed by different company and their protocols,features and security and privacy settings are different.
So in your situation, technically it is still creating the Calendar event in your Gmail account, and by the expected behaviour the creator of the event will receive the responses.

Alternate Solution / Suggestion:
If you want, you can setup auto forwarding to your non-gmail account. However, this will forward all emails you are receiving from your gmail to your non-gmail account.
Reference:
Sign in to your Google Account with another email address
